# Cannot create a distribution certification in Apple Developer website

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I want to create a distribution certificate in Apple Developer website, I have Administrator privilage, we already have 5 certificates in our account, when I tried to create a certificate the `Add iOS Certificate` screen is completly disable, not able to select any radio buttons on that.

Comment: I have "Administrator" access on my machine and you have "Administrator" access on your machine.  The real question is: are you the "team agent" for the Apple App Store account you're going to submit the app under?

Comment: I can do this. So check your access as in this link https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php

Comment: I am not a team agent, but I have an `Admin Role` for the itunes account on Apple Developer site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the apple document: `Each team can have only one active distribution certificate`, As the account I am using already had the distribution certificate, I was not able to create one. After deleting the existing distribution certificates, I was able to create a new distribution certificate