# Add iOS Certificate - The Generate button is disabled

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to generate a certificate for my new iPhone app.
I already did it before and had no problem.

Now when I try it, the *"Generate"* button is disabled.
I read in a *stackoverflow solution*, that I can create only one certificate.

[Cannot create a distribution certification in Apple Developer website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008255/cannot-create-a-distribution-certification-in-apple-developer-website)
(although I had 3)

So I deleted (Revoked) all of them.
It didn't help, and now I have no certificates.

Comment: Can you post some screenshot of what you are seeing? You only can have two distribution certificates at a time for one app. Also you should be very careful with revoking distribution certificates. Your app might stop working in appstore if you revoke wrong certificate.

Comment: I don't have points in stackoverflow to add a screenshot.
If you send me your email I can send you a screenshot.
I already made the mistake of revoking the certificates that I had, because I followed the suggestion in stackoverflow (see the link).

Comment: Did you upload the "Certificate Signing Request"?